# Trouble understanding proof for $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, rational-numbers

The density proof is that for every $x,y \in \mathbb{R}, \exists r \in \mathbb{Q} \ s.t \ x < r < y$

My professor gave an alternative proof to the one in Rudin. It starts by saying:

> By Archimedean property, $ \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \ s.t. \
> > n(y-x)>1$. Let $E=\{ m \in \mathbb{Z} : m < n \cdot y \} $.

(We want to show that E has a maximal element $m_0$ such that it $nx < m_0 < ny$ so that $\frac{m_0}{n}$ will be the fraction we want.)

> Claim: E has a maximal element. By a theorem, E will contain a Maximal if $E \neq \emptyset$ and if E is bounded above. By construction, $n \cdot y$ is an upper bound for E.

Here's the part I don't understand:

> By Archimedean property, $\exists m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ -m>-ny$ and $-m \in E$ so $E \neq \emptyset$.

I don't understand why we started taking negatives of the statement $ m < n \cdot y$. And how could $-m \in E$? I'm sorry if this is a really simple question, but this has been driving me crazy.

Comment: You're trying to find an element of $E$. The Archimedean property gives you integers *greater* than some given real number. Call it $z\in\Bbb N$ that's bigger than $-ny$. Then $z>-ny \implies -z<ny$, so $-z\in E$.

Comment: The first line of your post seems strange. Should it be quantified over $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ instead of $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh my goodness. I cannot believe I was stuck for so long on that. Thank you so much!

Comment: @BoltonBailey You are absolutely right. I'm going to make a quick edit. My notes on density was overlapping my other notes on proving the Archimedean property, so I probably typed that in without thinking. Thank you!